# Django - Access ForeignKey value without hitting database

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I have a django model like so:

```
class Profile_Tag(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
```

and a view like so:

```
pts = Profile_Tag.objects.all()
for pt in pts:
    print pt.profile.id
```

is there any way to access the profile foreignKey without hitting the database each time? I don't want to query the profile table. I just want to grab the ids from the Profile_Tag table.

Comment: How do you know it "hits" the database?  There is extensive cache management both in the ORM layer as well as the database.

Comment: Well, to anyone else reading this and to answer Lott's question...  it does do a DB hit in Django 1.4 (at least).  You can turn on the database logging to see all the queries and `pt.profile.id` results in a query while `pt.profile_id` does not.  It's possible for them to make the call to `.id` not result in a hit so it's possible this may change in the future (or already is different, I haven't tested newer versions).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
pt_ids = Profile_Tag.objects.values_list('profile', flat=True)
```

This will return you list of IDs. For model instance, there's another way:

```
pts = Profile_Tag.objects.all()
for pt in pts:
    print pt.profile_id
```

Comment: excellent. thank you. guess i should have thought to try that